# Removing .php file extension with .htaccess file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want www.example.com/about.php to just be www.example.com/about

I created an .htaccess file and placed it in the root of my server.
I am using linux shared hosting. PHP version 5.2

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

It seems that this code should work properly, but for some reason it does not. I get a 404 error when I try to navigate to a page without the .php extension.

Here's my markup too:

```html
<nav>
        <div class="container">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php" <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php')) echo 'class="current-nav"';?>>home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.php">about</a></li>
                <li><a href="services">our services</a></li>
                <li><a href="portfolio" <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'portfolio.php')) echo 'class="current-nav"';?>>portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="testimonials" <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'testimonials.php')) echo 'class="current-nav"';?>>testimonials</a></li>
                <!--<li><a href="#">client area</a></li>-->
                <li><a href="contact" <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'contact.php')) echo 'class="current-nav"';?>>Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="order" <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'order.php')) echo 'class="current-nav"';?>><strong>Free Quote</strong></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav><!--/navigation-->
```

You can see I tried using the php extension in the link and also tried without. The links with the php extension go to the page, but don't remove the extension.

I did a test to see if module_rewrite was enabled by putting in some garbage and returning a 500 error.

Comment: if your hosting is  shared, than try this article to get it done. http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/02/godaddy-remove-php-extension/

Comment: I generalized this question, since it doesn't appear to be specific to godaddy or php.

Answer (score 38):

Use this code for hiding/removing `.php` extension:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Comment: This option is the only one that worked for me with Godaddy as well. Thanks @anubhava

Comment: Other solutions allowed the page to render with or without the extension. For GoDaddy, this is the only solution that would remove the .php extension no matter what the link. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! Perfect for godaddy

Comment: This was indeed the only config that worked on GoDaddy!

Comment: After changing hosting and using Plesk Onyx instead of cPanel, the code I used to hide `.php` extensions stopped working. I have no idea why, but your code has completely solved the problem.

Answer (score 7):

So after a long bout with google I finally figured this one out. 
This works with Godaddy shared hosting.
It removes php file extensions so http://yoursite.com/about.php becomes http://yoursite.com/about

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    #If requested is not a filename...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    #And not a directory
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]          # perform this redirect
```

(remove comments before uploading to server)

Comment: But this is not correct solution as it rewrites any `/not-found` file to `/not-found.php` even if that php file doesn't exist in the system.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem also, but I found that this seemed to fix the GoDaddy .htaccess problem.

```
# Fix Rewrite
Options -Multiviews

# Mod Rewrite
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Fantastic @John SMith, this worked for Site5 hosting as well.

Comment: but i am godaddy user, mine is unlimited hosting, and its not working here.

Answer (score 1):

Pasted above everything in my .htaccess file worked for me...

```
## 301 Redirects
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.asp$ $1? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rule isn't correct, it's the wrong way round. Try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks for the input but no luck there. Still getting the 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

this work for me, with the Help of ChatGTP 4

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

# To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
# The condition checks if the .php version of the filename exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
# The condition checks that the request is not already for a .php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```