# Remove URL file ending (.php , .js , .asp etc)

Tags: php, html

I have a question about  removing the ending of a file in the url bar (the .something like `.php, .html, .js, .asp` part). My goal is such that whenever somebody is typing in the url something like `www.123.com/a`   where the file is, let's say a php file( so it's `a.php` ) so that people can type in **www.123.com/a**  instead of **www.123.com/a.php**. How do I fix this?

Is there some unique way to save files so that they are saved and can be called via the url just by its name? In my case, if I call `www.123.com/a` it will say `"object not found error"` but it will work for `www.123.com/a.php`.

How do I hide the .something part of a file in the url bar?

Additional notes, I use `notepad` so whenever I save I type in `a.php` as save as for PHP or `a.js` for javascript files.

Comment: David Harris's answer will give a perfect solution for removing file extensions. However, if you want to do some advanced rewriting, you should look more into it. (As Philip Whitehouse) has mentioned below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically this is done with `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for putting the technical side across. I was focussed on the general process.

Comment: I knew that word .htaccess sounded familiar, I've seen it on my server. What do i do with it? Where do i type in that code you put in? Do i put it in with the a.php file?

Comment: What I wrote is what should go in your `.htaccess `file.

Comment: Thanks, seems to work with that file. Quick question, for many . files would it go like " (.*) $1.php , $1.html, $1. etc?

Comment: You would have to use a similar set of rules checking that `.html` is a file, and rewriting to it if it is, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Use .htaccess!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10469791/1533203

http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2007/08/19/removing-file-extension-via-htaccess/

Answer (score 2):

> How do i fix this? Is there some unique way to save files so that they
>   are saved and can be called via the url just by its name?

No.

What actually happens is we get the web server to re-write the requests before they get to PHP.

So the user might type (or be sent to):

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026969/remove-url-file-ending-php-js-asp-etc`

Apache (or whatever web server you are using) will then re-write that to something like:

`http://stackoverflow.com/index.php?page=questions&id=14026969&title=remove-url-file-ending-php-js-asp-etc`

From which we can process it.

Answer (score 0):

create  .htaccess file if is bot exist on repo folder  and add that code to it

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```