# How to hide .html extension in url using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to hide `.html` extension from URL using JavaScript.

FOR ex:

`mysite.html` hide.html here from url

Comment: I don't know with javascript, but if you are using PHP as a serverside language you just open localhost/folder_name/index.php as localhost/folder_name

Comment: @VikasSangle That has nothing to do with the language but with the server settings / hosting settings, like IIS, etc. Ontopic: Why would you even want to do this? Hiding stuff for people isn't really a way to go, unless you are talking about url rewriting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026969/remove-url-file-ending-php-js-asp-etc

Comment: You are always seeing the page you are requesting through HTTP. A clientside language cannot decide which response you get from your server.

Comment: I also don't know why this is downvoted- I think most people just don't realize that html5 allows you to modify the url without reloading the page. The guy never said what server he was running, either

Answer (score 2):

You cannot achieve this through javascript, this need to be done through `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

More information about `mod_rewrite` module [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can with html5, but also you can use url rewriting, or seo friendly urls, on the server side.

```
window.history.pushState({"html":'<html></html>',"pageTitle":'this is my title'},"", 'http://stackoverflow.com/mynewurl');
```

However keep in mind you can only change the url to one which is the same domain as the original!

There is a great library called [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) which helps with cross browser and version compatibility