# Add extensionless url to page via onclick javascript function (collapsible element)

Tags: javascript, html, url, pushstate

This is my button.  It loads the correct page with javascript onclick function, but when the content is loaded into the div, I would like the address bar to indicate a new extension-less URL.  How can I include a URL rewrite in the javascript function?

**HTML**

```
<img src="image1.png" type="button" onclick="myFunction()"  data-        
toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" 
aria-controls="collapseExample"/>


<section id="content">This is the content</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
$('section#content').load("content/page1.php");};
/*What should I write here???? to make url 
www.home.com/my-extensionless-url-name */
</script>
```

I tried push state, but I didn't seem to be getting the correct element reference.

Comment: it's a matter of your php framework. You should look into MVC-based frameworks

Comment: That's not really the response I'm looking for.  I'm aware of MVC frameworks though, thank you.  I'm looking for a specific function to target this collapsible element within the given function.

Comment: you can'thide from javascript the page extension. MVC does not uses extensions, however there are other [non-javascript solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21251449/how-to-hide-html-extension-in-url-using-javascript) to get what you want.

Comment: I added an href field to the html element and tried this code.           function myFunction() {
  
 $('section#content').load("content/gpage1.php");

  event.preventDefault();     

  // Detect if pushState is available
  if(history.pushState) {
    history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href'));
  }
  return false;
      
};

Comment: By the way, I'm basically using an MVC file structure.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found the answer.  Here is the function that works, and makes it extensionless!

```
function myFunction(){
    $('section#content').load("content/page1.php");
    event.preventDefault();     
    window.history.pushState(
        {"html":"<html></html>",
        "pageTitle":"this is my title"},
        "", "http://my_Specific_Website.com/mynewurl"
    );
};
```

Comment: What if the client refreshes the page? I'm going to assume you will end up on the 404 page?

Comment: So bookmarking your pages would also be an issue. Client bookmark your page to view later or send the url to a friend to share, they will be on the 404 page (Page not found) The client might not bother searching since they think the page has been removed. I would recommend using `.htaccess` Maybe alter the url a little `http://doamin.com/content/mynewurl` This will allow you to url rewrite for anything trying to target `http://domain.com/content/a-z` => `http://domain.com/a-z.html`

Comment: Thanks very much!  That was very helpful.