# URL rewrite with htaccess to get trailing /

Tags: html, .htaccess, url-rewriting

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.html to /dir/foo

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]
```

Im using the above code snippet for URL re-write as suggested in [Removing .php file extension with .htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462799/removing-php-file-extension-with-htaccess-file-godaddy). But i'm not able to add training / to the URL

for example www.somewebsite.com/contact to www.somewebsite.com/contact/

What is that i've to correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/index\.html$ $1/ [NE,R=302,L]

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.html to /dir/foo    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L,NC]

# add trailing extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)[^/][?\s]
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302,NE]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]
```

Comment: It didn't make any change and didn't add the training slash, it's still the same.

Comment: Added the training slash but broke all the other links of js, css and images too. like "http://somewebsite.com/images/logo.png/"

Comment: That is due to your use of relative paths. For that you can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: Yup fixed. Thanks @anubhava