# .htaccess hide page extension

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, plesk

Whenever I attempt to hide the `.php` extension with `.htacess` and go to a page using the `.php` extension all that is displayed on the screen is "Page Not Found". I had it working perfectly before, but I have recently changed hosting companies and now I am using  `Plesk Onyx 17.0.17` with `CentOS Linux 7.3.1611` and `PHP 7.1.4`.

Here are the contents of my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Multiviews -Indexes

# Disable Automatic Directory detection
DirectorySlash Off

ErrorDocument 404 /!404.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Remove trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/+$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Is it using apache or nginx. If it is using nginx, this file does nothing.

Comment: @AndrewRayner `mod_rewrite` is an `Apache` module

Comment: @PedroLobito Right, but he said it stopped working when he switched hosts. Which means that if he was using apache before. This would of worked.

Comment: I am using Apache and possibly Nginx as well. However, I can confirm my `.htaccess` file is being used because I've tried making changes to it, and it's the only way I've managed to get my custom 404 page to work. 
Also, because of the .php extension I think prevents `Additional directives for HTTPS` and `Additional nginx directives` from being used to set my 404 page, so it has to be  done with .htaccess.

Comment: If I put garbage at the top of my `.htaccess` file, I get a 500 error. However, if I comment out this line `RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]`, the redirect is still performed.

Comment: What do you mean by `the redirect is still performed`? What URI you enter in browser and what does it become?

Comment: https://www.websemantica.com/index still redirects to https://www.websemantica.com even when the line `RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]` has been commented out. Also, I can't even load my site from Firefox. On Firefox, I receive no errors, it just behaves as if I did not type anything into the address box. I tried clearing all history including cache and restarting and it makes no difference.

Comment: My sites loads on Firefox after I reinstalled it, but I have no idea what caused that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have it working now thanks to [Anubhava's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462799/removing-php-file-extension-with-htaccess-file). I still have no idea why my old could would not work though.

Here is the code that I used to solve the problem:

```
## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```